# Ajax Tabs for Wordpress that loads and runs different shortcodes when user changes the tab

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

How does one execute a shortcode, which is placed in a tab, only when the user clicks on the Tab's Title. How do we do this for five tabs? MY objective is to reduce load time of me website. So, only that content which the user wants must load when he clicks on the tab.

I'm fairly certain the best way to do this is by utilizing Wordpress's admin-ajax.php. I've searched a great deal. And I've found most of the code (I think) to create the AJAX tabs. But, when I fire the code it doesn't show up. Rather the HTML shows us, the AJAX doesn't.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.my_tabs a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var tab_id = $('this').attr('id');


    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
      dataType: 'html',
      data: ({
        action: 'my_tab_menu',
        id: tab_id
      }),
      success: function(data) {
        $('#my_tab' + tab_id).html(data);
      },
      error: function(data) {
        alert("Error!");
        return false;
      }

    });

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="my_tabs">
  <a href="#my_tab1" id="my_tab_id_1">Tab 1</a>
  <a href="#my_tab2" id="my_tab_id_2">Tab 2</a>
  <a href="#my_tab3" id="my_tab_id_3">Tab 3</a>
  <a href="#my_tab4" id="my_tab_id_4">Tab 4</a>
  <a href="#my_tab5" id="my_tab_id_5">Tab 5</a>
</div>

<div class="my_section" id="my_tab1">
  <?php echo do_shortcode ('[shortcode-1]'); ?>
</div>

<div class="my_section" id="my_tab2">
  <?php echo do_shortcode ('[shortcode-2]'); ?>
</div>

<div class="my_section" id="my_tab3">
  <?php echo do_shortcode ('[shortcode-3]'); ?>
</div>

<div class="my_section" id="my_tab4">
  <?php echo do_shortcode ('[shortcode-4]'); ?>
</div>

<div class="my_section" id="my_tab5">
  <?php echo do_shortcode ('[shortcode-5]'); ?>
</div>
```

I add all the code directly into the page using a page-builder. So, I'm not using functions.php to add_action for this particular tab that I'm trying to implement.

I found all the code from a similar post on stackover:
[Ajax tabs (wordpress)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31394844/ajax-tabs-wordpress)

They call template_parts into the tabs. Where as I want to execute a shortcode.

I'm what you'd call a coding bimbo. All help shall be much appreciated.

Thank you. And if you've managed to read till here, you deserve to have a pleasant day. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so you can't achieve it the way you have laid your `template`. As soon as you `echo` the `shortcode` and the **browser renders** the page, the `shortcode` contents must have printed. You need to create a `custom-page-template.php`, create a page and on that page you need to send the `shortcode` handler as soon as you click on the `tab` through `GET` or `POST` method using `ajax`.

In your **Custom Template** you receive the `[shortcode-1]`. An example code would be like you see below:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Shortcode Processor
*/
$current_shortcode = $_POST['shortcode_name'];
?>
<div id="shortcode-contents">
<?php echo do_shortcode($current_shortcode); ?>
</div>
```

Now you have the response in your Ajax Call. You can now inject the success html inside your desired tab.

Comment: Thank you so much Atiqur for the reply. It works! I will soon post the complete code on here once I've formatted it. Have a great day. You deserve a falooda for this. :D

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
         <button class="tabs" id="my-tabid1" data-target=".my-section1.box">Tab 1</button>
         <button class="tabs" id="my-tabid2"  data-target=".my-section2.box">Tab 2</button>
         <button class="tabs" id="my-tabid3" data-target=".my-section3.box">Tab 3</button>


        <div class="my_section1 box active" id="my-tab1">
           <?php echo do_shortcode ('[shortcode-1]'); ?>
        </div>

        <div class="my-section2 box" id="my-tab2">
          <?php echo do_shortcode ('[shortcode-1]'); ?>
        </div>

        <div class="my-section3 box" id="my_tab3">
           <?php echo do_shortcode ('[shortcode-1]'); ?>
        </div>
<style>
.box {
  display: none;
}
.box.active {
  display: block;
}
</style>
        <script>
        $('.tabs').on('click', function(){
          var $target = $($(this).data('target'));
          $target.siblings().removeClass('active');
          $target.addClass('active');
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much varzesht for the code. I tried it. It works wells. But, its calling all the shortcodes at the same time when the page loads. I want it to only load one shortcode '[shortcode-1]' when the page loads and '[shortcode-2]',  '[shortcode-3]' should load when the user clicks on: Tab 2, Tab 3 respectively.

Comment: Remove the active class from div first `<div class="my_section1 box" id="my-tab1">`

Comment: Nope. Checked my Console panel. All the shortcodes are loading when the page loads. I think you've misunderstood my earlier statement. When I say load, I don't mean into the front end, what the user sees. I mean in the browser. In the start, when a page loads, the browser should only load one shortcode. And then, when the user clicks another tab, the browser, via Ajax, calls the shortcode and loads the new shortcode into the content part of the tabs for the user to see.

Comment: Varzesht, thank you for taking the time to reply. I wish you a pleasant day.