# Wordpress Ajax call only works with console.log debugging

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

So I am building a user profile section in front-end Wordpress, and loading different content dynamically in jQuery tabs to break up the UI a bit. I early on switched from loading this all in on page load to using ajax to call in the php files for the user profile only on demand.

This was not working so I added a console.log to the success action to see what is going on. Funnily this function works to load in the php files, but ONLY IF I have console.log enabled. To be clear, when I check the network tab under XHR requests, both with console.log and without console.log I get a 200 status back from the server, it just doesn't render if I am not declaring that success action to the console.

Any ideas why?

```
    $('.profileTabs ul li a').click(function(e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            var tab_id = $(this).attr('id'); 

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: cyberAjax.ajaxurl, 
                dataType: 'html',
                data: ({ 
                    action: 'ajax_load_tabs', id: tab_id
                }),
                success: function(data){
                          
                          $('#tab'+tab_id).html(data);
                          console.log( $('#tab-'+tab_id).html(data) );

                },
                error: function(data)  
                {  
                alert("Error!");
                return false;
                }  

            }); 

    });
```

For reference, my approach was influenced by [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31394844/ajax-tabs-wordpress).

So I have the below in my functions.php - this all works with console.log so I don't think the cause lies here:

```
function ajax_load_tabs() {

$tab_id = $_GET['id'];

if ($tab_id == 'ui-id-7') {get_template_part( '/page-templates/dashboard/broker-dashboard', 'onboarding' );}
elseif ($tab_id == 'ui-id-8') {get_template_part( '/page-templates/dashboard/broker-dashboard', 'tasks' );}
elseif ($tab_id == 'ui-id-9') {get_template_part( '/page-templates/dashboard/broker-dashboard', 'incidents' );}

die();

}
    
add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_load_tabs', 'ajax_load_tabs');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_load_tabs', 'ajax_load_tabs');
```

Comment: Remove `type` and `dataType` from ajax, then in `ajax_load_tabs` change `$_GET` to `$_REQUEST` and try again.

Comment: Are you using [$( document ).ready()](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) ?

Comment: That's great - making those changes makes it work without console.log, but I am still not clear on why it happens in the first place.

Comment: Yes using document ready