# how to built ajax tabs in wordpress?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, tabs

I try to display the departments in my website as tabs, when click one tab it will display the data related to this department according to department_id.

I try this code [Execute php function only when clicked (wordpress)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31331953/execute-php-function-only-when-clicked-wordpress/31332113?noredirect=1#comment50652111_31332113)  but I need the tabs number to be dynamic.

```
<div class="tabs">
<ul>
    <?php
        $arr1=array(2,3,5,10,22,25,27,28,29,30);    

        $arr2=array("dep1","dep2","dep3","dep4",
        "dep5","dep6","dep7","dep8","dep9","dep10");

        for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){?>
            <li><a href="#tab" id="<?php echo $arr1[$i]; ?>"><?php echo 
                 $arr2[$i];?>
            </a></li>
    <?php  } ?>
 </ul>
 </div>


 <div id="tab" class="section">

 </div>
```

functions.php:

```
<?php
 add_action('wp_ajax_tabsfunction', 'tabsfunction');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_tabsfunction', 'tabsfunction');

function tabsfunction() {
$dept_id=$_GET[id];
/** Here I print data according to $dept_id **/
die();
}
?>
```

script.js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('.tabs a').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

var tab_id = jQuery(this).attr('id'); 

console.log(tab_id);
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                   url: "wp-admin/admin-ajax.php", 
                    dataType: 'html',
                    data: ({ action: 'tabsfunction', id: tab_id}),
                    success: function(data){
                               jQuery('#tab').html(data);
                    },
                  error: function(data)  
                    {  
                   alert("Error!");
                    return false;
                }  });}); });
```

it dose not work, it displays data only for one tab.
    console.log(tab_id) ---->  it display the id for the first tab clicked 
    and did not change when click another tab.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `echo` the output from the `tabsfunction` and also add the `die()` at end of the function like below :

```
add_action('wp_ajax_tabsfunction', 'tabsfunction');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_tabsfunction', 'tabsfunction');

function tabsfunction() {
  $dept_id=$_GET[id];
/** Here display data according to $dept_id **/
   echo 'output';
   die();
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I realy added die() function and output the result to my code in local server, but I forgot to add it here, Because the original code is long, and what I wrote here is a shortcut to the idea.I will edit it ...but tabs still does'nt work

Comment: Please check `echo $arr1($i);` inside the loop. It should be `echo $arr1[$i];`

Answer (score 0):

can you please correct your tab list code.

```
<div class="tabs">
            <ul>
                <?php
                $arr1 = array(2,3,5,10,22,25,27,28,29,30);
                $arr2 = array("dep1","dep2","dep3","dep4","dep5","dep6","dep7","dep8","dep9","dep10");
                for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
                {
                    ?>
                    <li><a href="#tab" id="<?php echo $arr1[$i]; ?>"><?php echo $arr2[$i];?></a></li>
                <?php 
                }
                ?>
             </ul>
             </div>
       <?php for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
             {
                 ?>
                <div id="tab<?php echo $arr1[$i]; ?>" class="section">
                </div>
             <?php 
             }
             ?>
```

Also return proper response on ajax request.

```
<?php
add_action('wp_ajax_tabsfunction', 'tabsfunction');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_tabsfunction', 'tabsfunction');

function tabsfunction() {
 $dept_id = $_GET[id];
 echo $dept_id; // this just dispay requsted id as tab content here you can add your logic for dynamic content based on id
die();
}
?>
```

And your script js look like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('.tabs a').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

var tab_id = jQuery(this).attr('id'); 

console.log(tab_id);
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "GET",
               url: "wp-admin/admin-ajax.php", 
                dataType: 'html',
                data: ({ action: 'tabsfunction', id: tab_id}),
                success: function(data){
                           jQuery('#tab'+tab_id).html(data);
                },
              error: function(data)  
                {  
               alert("Error!");
                return false;
            }  });}); });
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, okay the tabs list is correct in my local server and there is'nt any syntax error and I add my dynamic code to tabsfunction() function.. but why must add tab_id to   jQuery('#tab'+tab_id).html(data); ?  tab_id: refers to category id ... also if I add it , tabs still does'nt work